# Vocal group couples ordering

Tags: combinatorics

**A vocal group consisting of alf,bill,cal,deb,eve, and fay (3 boys and 3 girls) are deciding how to arrange themselves from left to right on a stage. How many ways to this if**

**There are 3 couples (Alf and Deb,Bill and Eve, cal and fay), and the two member of each couple want to stand next to each other.**

One one the ways to order the couple is

AD BE CF

A standing for alf,B for bill and so on.

So you have 3! possible way to organize the couple and you must chose whether the boy or girl is left most.

So would it be $3!(2)$

Comment: You need $3!2^3$. For once the couples order has been determined ($3!$ ways), for **each** couple the older of the two people in the couple can be on the left or the right of the younger. So $2\times 2\times 2$ choices.

Comment: I see so the 3! is for the order of three couples and the 2 is when you chose oldest of each couple boy or girl, and the three is because you repeat this for the three couples.

Comment: Yes, you have described the reason well.  I used older/younger in order not to make assumptions about sex of couples. I am undoubtedly out of date, but aren't boys and girls a little on the young side for coupling?

Comment: Who is to say in the age we live in...